# Two very basic question in DEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have two questions in DEs that may seem very basic, but I couldn't really find any satisfying answers for them.

First, regarding the order of the DE, why does the DE has to posses solutions equal to its order? Can I find a proof of that anywhere? Is it like the fundamental theorem of Algebra?

Second, suppose I found two similar solutions for a second order DE, why do I need to find another solution that is linearly independent of them? What's wrong with the two solutions being the same? Or in other words, why do the solutions of the DEs have to be linearly independent?
Giving an algebraic analog for this $(x-1)^2 = 0$, gives $x = 1$, but we don't proceed to find another solution because the two solutions are the same.

I would appreciate any clarifications or sources. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).
I tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: I think that every ODE book for mathematicians explain this. The proof goes through the "existing and uniqueness theorem" and the wronskian.

Answer (score 0):

For one you might be interested into looking why the Wronskian is important here is a link that gives relevant information. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FundamentalSetsofSolutions.aspx#Wronskian

(2) because we can then form a fundamental set of solutions which in turns allows us to find a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about **linear** differential equations!

There are differential equations of first order which have $2$ or more solutions. for example:
\begin{align}
    (f'-g)(f'-h) = 0
\end{align}
This is obviously a first order differential equation but it is **not linear**. The solutions can be calculated by $f = \int g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ and $f = \int h(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$. If you choose $h$ and $g$ linearly independent then you have more linear independent solution than the order of the equation.

If you have a **linear** differntial equation like:
\begin{align}
5f'-3f=0
\end{align}
then every linear combination of a solution will be also be a solution to the problem that is due the fact that the equation is linear in $f$ -- maybe you should look up what that exactly means.

Answer (score 0):

We look for new solutions of DE because we want to know all of them. If $f$ is one solution, then although $f+c$ for a constant $c$ might be a new solution, it is only superficially different. For example, the difference between value at 1 and 0 in both cases is the same. Thus, one justifiably wonders if there are really different solutions.

There is no guarantee that DE will have exactly as many independent solutions as its order. There are restrictions to be put on its type, and so on. You are right in asking for a proof.